# Load selected/active tab content in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm having a view pager in an application which is dynamically populated based on content available on server i.e tabs in view pager is variable. To do this I have created a single fragment which is binds to each tabs inside view pager.

I have populated viewpager like this:

```
    List lstFragments = lstFragments = new ArrayList();
    lstFragments.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(cat.getId(), subcategoryId, cat.getName(), subcategoryName, subcategoryIconUrl));
    DetailsTabsAdapter pageAdapter = new DetailsTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), lstFragments);

    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

By default viewpager has property that its load content for one previous and one next fragment, but I don't want this.

**What I want to achieve:**

1. Load content of only selected/active tab.
2. At the same time once content is loaded for that tab I don't want to
   load it again from server if user comes back.

**How to achieve above functionality?**

**What I have did to achieve this:**

1. I have loaded content from server in fragment's `public View
   onCreateView()` lifecycle event. Content is loading fine but it
   loads content for other tab as well.
2. Then I tried `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`. But it also not working.

Please help me out to resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: You need to override `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` and you are done :) Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Issue 1**

You need to implement `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` like below:

```
boolean isDataLoaded = false;

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser && !isDataLoaded ) {

            loadData();//Load data from server here
            isDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Above code will load data only when your fragment will be visible to user and `isDataLoaded` flag ensure that content is loaded once per fragment lifecycle.

**For issue 2**

You need to store data you want to show to user as global within that fragment in your case `DetailsFragment` and check its value before loading it from server. May be you can do like below code.

```
boolean isDataLoaded = false;

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser && !isDataLoaded ) {

            loadData();//Load data from server here
            isDataLoaded = true;
        }
        else if(isDataLoaded && yourData != null)
        {
            //Load your data from cache or existing global instance here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exact solution to my problem. Thanks Geek

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `setUserVisibleHint()` you can override it in your `Frament`. Which is called when the Fragment is visible. Now you can call the service to load data inside that method. And at the same time in the same method check for data if it is already loaded (saved in db) then call the service otherwise load the data from saved once.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    // check if fragment is visible
    if (isVisibleToUser) {

    if(mdata == null){
    callService();
    } else{
    loadFromSavedDB();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you fragment call this

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
            //Do what you want here`enter code here`

        }
    }
```